# Hiding ViewFlipper TableLayouts

Tags: android

I have a view flipper where I slide from view 1 through to 3. Is there a way I can programatically hide the views that are not needed so that the user doesn't have a blank view to flip through?

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <!--adding views to ViewFlipper-->

            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="View 1" android:textSize="25sp" android:textColor="@color/lightpurple"></TextView>
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="View 2" android:textSize="25sp" android:textColor="@color/lightpurple"></TextView>
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="View 3" android:textSize="25sp" android:textColor="@color/lightpurple"></TextView>
            </TableLayout>

        </ViewFlipper>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the visibility to View.GONE, it makes the view invisible but also means that it doesn't use space in the layout, according to the doc anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you *programatically hide the views* by setting its visibility to `View.INVISIBLE` or to remove a view by `View.GONE`
But i think you need to skip some child, and you are using `viewflipper.next()`, Then its better to use `ViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(whichChild)`